# Nginx reverse proxy causing file downloads to take excessive time to start

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, php-fpm, amazon-s3

## Overview

My web app allows users to upload files which are stored on s3 via my servers. When a user requests a file my web server retrieves it from s3 then sends it on to the client.

I recently deployed a load balancer making my current set up as follows:

[image: Web app Server setup]

Note currently I only have a single webserver to simplify debugging.

## Initial Problem

After I deployed the load balancer I noticed that downloads of larger files (anything bigger than around 4 MB) would fail with 504  gateway timeout after 60 seconds.

I looked at the load balancer nginx error log for the site and I was seeing a few entries like:

```
[error] 11770#11770: *40 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: XXXX, ...
```

When I looked at the web server nginx error log for the site I saw a similar entries:

```
[error] 6632#6632: *41 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: ...
[error] 6632#6632: *85 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: ...
[error] 7163#7163: *41 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: ...
[error] 7505#7505: *41 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: ...
[error] 7505#7505: *91 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: ....
```

And looking at the php-fpm error logs on the web server I had:

```
WARNING: [pool www] child 3011, script '/home/forge/XXX.com/public/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php") execution timed out (64.950545 sec), terminating
WARNING: [pool www] child 3011 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 1140.059968 seconds from start
WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it
WARNING: [pool www] child 4260, script '/home/forge/XXX.com/public/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php") execution timed out (68.171099 sec), terminating
WARNING: [pool www] child 4260 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 160.005837 seconds from start
NOTICE: [pool www] child 4271 started
```

I put this down to not having my php execution timeouts and nginx connection timeouts too low so I increased them by doing the following:

- On the load balancer:

  - Add `proxy_read_timeout 600s;` to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
- On the web server:

  - In nginx site config I added `fastcgi_read_timeout 600;` to the .php location block.
  - Added `max_execution_time = 600` and `default_socket_timeout = 600` to the php-fpm configuration.
  - Added `request_terminate_timeout = 300` to /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

**This fixed my initial problem to a degree as I can now download larger files (tested up to 25 MB).**

## Next Problem - Slow downloads

After the config changes above I can download files without a timeout however it takes an excessive amount of time for the download to start (~300seconds) and the actual download itself is slow (minor concern).

The flow for downloading a file is as follows:

- Client clicks uri link that hits my server
- My web server goes to the database and gets information such as hashed file name and path for the db server.
- The web server then retrieves the file from S3.
- The web server responds with the file as a download to the initial request:

For reference the function running on the web server to do this is:

```php
public function show($projectID, $documentID, $revisionID, $fileID)
{
    $fileEntry = File::find($fileID);

    $path = $fileEntry->path();
    $file = Storage::get($path);
    $size = Storage::size($path);

    return Response::make($file, 200)
            ->header('Content-Type', $fileEntry->mime)
            ->header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . $fileEntry->original_filename . '"')
            ->header('Content-Length:', $size);
}
```

I understand that I am double handling the files and in the future will switch to signed s3 url redirects but there are other parts of the application where this will not be practical (grabbing a collection of files, zipping and sending to client) and therefore would like to gain some understanding.

What could be the cause of this issue? I don't believe I ever encountered this issue prior to deploying the load balancer.

If I download the file directly from s3 the download times are a fraction of the overall time when coming via my server, therefore I don't believe that double handling is the issue. Could it be buffer or memory size related?

Additional Information:

- Laravel forge used to provision and the servers.
- SSL termination on the load balancer
- Laravel web app
- Linode's all hosted in the Singapore data centre
- S3 region is Sydney
- Issues were observed at extremely low traffic (down to 1 client)

Comment: So your path is ELB -> Nginx -> Apache -> php-fpm. What is the purpose of Nginx - why both that and Apache? These types of problems are very difficult to diagnose from just words - can you give a URL to try?

Comment: No the path is Nginx (LB) -> Nginx (web server) -> php-fpm. Unfortunately its all secured and has no public url to try.

Comment: So you have two Nginx instances? If one is a load balancer how many back end web servers do you have? If you want useful advice you're going to have to give more information, more clearly.

Comment: Yes I have two nginx instances (see question edits). Currently I only have one back end web server to simplify what I'm looking at. Let me know any additional information I can provide.

Comment: A few thoughts. 1) Can you please clearly label load balancer, web server, and php logs. Ideally correlate them for a number of sample requests. 2) Nginx doesn't have a php configuration, you configure php-fpm directly, but timeouts are in Nginx obviously. 3) There are many, many unknowns here. Hopefully someone can give you some ideas, but I think you're going to have to go back to first principles of problem solving.

Comment: @Tim I have rewritten the question to hopefully add some clarity to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Nice edit, things are much more clear.

It seems like this is an application timeout in PHP. My best guess is that PHP is completely downloading the large files to a temporary location then returning them, rather than streaming them back directly. This accounts for the latency, though not so much for the slow speed. I don't even know if direct streaming is practical direct from S3 back through your stack - research if required (by you). I'd also see if PHP5 makes a difference, I've found PHP7 less reliable in a couple of edge cases.

I'd track the exact timings for when requests come in, hit each server, and responses are returned by each server so you can track request fully. This is especially true in the PHP layer, add logging for when the app server receives the request, when it fetches from S3, and when it starts sending it back to the client.

Download speed is slightly puzzling. I would find a way to test the speed between your PHP server and S3 - do a curl or something - it could be a simple bandwidth problem, or latency decreasing bandwidth available. A workaround might be to use CloudFront, but probably not, as this will only accelerate downloads the second time they're requested, not the first.

Once you done all this if you haven't worked it out post the information you discover - especially the exact times that a few requests hit each layer, and times that responses get returned.

Comment: Yes I believe it completely downloads the file thats why I was wondering whether I need some changes various buffer configs. I am able to stream the files however I haven't yet found a solution for streaming a bunch of files into a zip archive and sending that to the client.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to zip them then stream that out. It might be possible with some kind of streaming compression algorithm, maybe, but if you want them downloaded, packaged into a zip, then sent to the client that's an interesting challenge. I don't know how to do that off the top of my head.

Comment: Check the latency between PHP server and S3 using traceroute. That would indicate where the bottlenecks are.